# Angular 6 - Routing correctly when importing a library/npm module with child routes

Tags: angular, routes, node-modules, angular6, ng-packagr

I have built an Angular 6 Library module following this [guide](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-part-2-6e2bc1e14121) and a dummy application running along my library so I can import and test modules during development.

The Library Module I am importing from the Library has child routes. Which I think is the root cause of this problem. Pun intended. The routing module for the Library Module looks like this:

```
// Library Module routing
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    children: [
        { path: '', component: LoginFormComponent },
        { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordFormComponent }
    ]
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {}
```

In my dummy application I have a Modules module that is lazy loaded by the App Routing module:

```
// Dummy app root routing
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children:  [{
            path: 'modules',
            loadChildren: './modules/modules.module#ModulesModule'
        }]
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The Modules module file is where I import the Library Module and looks like this:

```
// Dummy app modules routing
import { LoginModule } from '@library-namespace/modules';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        LoginModule.forRoot(environment)
    ],
    declarations: [ ModulesComponent ]
})
export class ModulesModule { }
```

When navigating to localhost:4200/modules the Library Module is instantiated even when the modules.component.html file doesn't have the component selector of the Library Module. All other ocntent in my modules.component.html file doesn't appear either. I think this is because the root path of the Library Module is ' ' ? I need to include the component selector as I pass in the function to watch for the eventEmitter. The selector looks like this:

```
<lib-login (loginEvent)="login($event)"></lib-login>
```

I want to navigate in my dummy application to localhost:4200/modules display the Library Module and capture the event emitter in the modules component of the dummy application.

Comment: I've been having a similar issue which appears to be down to this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can you update w/ a resolution if you found one?

Comment: I don't know if you can have the double empty path in the lazy module from path to children- did you try just having the 2 "children" as two paths where you have the one path?